# Embedding video on Facebook profile doesn't work

Tags: facebook, video, embed, facebook-opengraph

I do have a video sharing website. Have everything setup, open graph tags according to specifications. When I share a video on Facebook everything looks fine (thumb, link, title, description) but the embedded player doesn't show up on the page, shows a blank flash movie

So my question is what am I doing wrong, how can I debug this thing, because I see no way out of this. It would have help if I could see the code used by Facebook, but I can't so I have no way to debug this

URL Eg. http://evahd.com/vutzN

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="Frenetic kinetics">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://evahd.com/vutzN">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://evahq.com/mp/1/vutzN-2.jpg">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://v.evahd.com/vutzN">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="360">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="EvaHD">
```

Thank you